# How to stop the black screens when navigating from one activity to another in xamarin android mono

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working in a project where many black screens are appearing while I am navigating from one activity to another activity in. our application is completely based on net so for every activity there is some API calling in background hope this is the problem of all and also implemented page loading but that did not solve the problem. I had not got the reason of the black screens during the navigation between the activities. Can help me with the reason of that and solution for solving the problem.

Comment: Without seeing code of what you are doing it's hard to guess. One thing could be that you are doing your calls in the Main Thread and this might be causing these black screens but as I said without code this is just guessing

Comment: There is no way to help without see the code that is being run when one of your Activities is instantiated, but as @apineda stated, you might be blocking the UI thread / doing to much work on that thread. Go into the Developer Options on the device and enable "Strict mode enabled", that will visually show you excessive UI-thread based work by flashing the screen border in red....

Comment: Oh that's grate to know that it's the problem causing due to using complete code on main thread. Thankyou (I am not supposed to post the code so please don't mind)

Answer (score 1):

When you navigating from one `Activity` to another, if your layout file is too large or your `Activity` load too much data when your `Activity` is Created, your `Activity` will first show the default black background. You can solve the problem by modifying the style of the `Activity` :

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
```

Use it in `Activity` you want navigate to :

```
 [Activity(Label = "Activity1", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of scenarios the best solution it's to load only the indispensable in the onCreate/onResume events, and load the rest of the information in background.

Fortunately you are using xamarin and you have async methods to solve this.